# How to access message in DioError

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I access the "Message" field inside the e
[image]

My postRequest function:

```html
  Future<Response> postRequest(String endPoint, dynamic data) async {
    Response response;

    try {
      if (data != null) {
        response = await _dio!.post(endPoint, data: data);
      } else {
        response = await _dio!.post(endPoint);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      //I can reach the message from here and return it, but this 
      is not what I want to do.

      if (e is DioError) print(e.response);
      throw Exception(e);
    }

    return response;
  }
```

where I want to reach the message:

```html
      var response;
      try{
        response = await http.postRequest("Stok/$type", requestObj);
      }catch(e){
        print("message....: $e");
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Future<Response> postRequest(String endPoint, dynamic data) async {
Response response;

try {
  if (data != null) {
    response = await _dio!.post(endPoint, data: data);
  } else {
    response = await _dio!.post(endPoint);
  }
  return response;
} on DioError {
  rethrow; // or throw e;
}
}
```

Now, just call it like that

```
 var response;
  try{
    response = await http.postRequest("Stok/$type", requestObj);
  } on DioError catch(e){
    print("message....: ${e.message}");
  }
```

Comment: unfortunately it didn't work

Comment: I/flutter (29579): type '_Exception' is not a subtype of type 'DioError' in type cast

Comment: Can you show the code snippet

Comment: I update the answer check that

Comment: This worked. Really thank you so much. You saved me a lot of trouble :D